# AWS tomcat hibernate logback logging

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, logback

Having a terrible time getting logging data from hibernate on a tomcat server at AWS.

I'm running into a problem on the server that is database connection related.  Over time we lose the ability to connect to the database.  Web page shows up but hangs connecting to the database. I started searching the code base for missing closes... found a few and that has made things better.  However, I still want to see the log output from hibernate and c3p0.

I add this logback file to the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT"
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %class - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!--Daily rolling file appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>logs/pedalcoach-web.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>logs/web.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I endup getting a nice rolling log file of all my web log statements in web.log but nothing from hibernate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Very odd, seems like I get all the logging that I expect on my local server but no org.hibernate log message when I deploy to AWS.

Comment: Seeing them is testing, but I'm not sure if they are even on my localserver....sigh.